# PHP Change object field value by passing its name from variable

Tags: php, variables, object

I tried to do it by myself, but Google doesn't understand me. Question seems easy, unless I couldn't find answer.

I've got some object, and I want to change its value, so I can do it eg.

```
$obj->field_suffix1 = "Abracadabra";
```

The problem is that i want to pass "suffix1" from variable, so I would do if it was array

```
$obj['field_'.$suffix] = "Abracadabra";
```

Any suggestion?
Thank you in advice!
Dominik.

Answer (score 2):

Try,

```
$obj->field_{$suffix} = "Abracadabra";
```

Comment: You seem to have a bracket and then a curly brace

Answer (score 0):

Use the `$obj->$prop` syntax:

```
o=new StdClass();
$p="someprop";
$o->$p="someval";
print_r($o);

//stdClass Object
//(
//    [someprop] => someval
//)
```

**EDIT**

Just to make that clear: I ment `$p="field_$suffix"; $obj->$p = "Abracadabra";`

Comment: Simpliest solution - the same as above ;) Great, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

This should be enough :

```
$yourfield = "field_".$suffix;
$obj->$yourfield = "Abracadabra";
```

Comment: That's it! Simple solution! I couldn't imagine it's SO simple! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This works fine: https://eval.in/92882

```
$obj = array();
$suffix = "suffix1";
$key = 'field_'.$suffix;
$obj[$key] = "Abracadabra";

var_dump($obj);
```